# Is there a way to instantiate a class without calling __init__?

Tags: python, class, constructor, instantiation

Is there a way to circumvent the constructor `__init__` of a class in python?

Example:

```
class A(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        print "FAILURE"

    def Print(self):
        print "YEHAA"
```

Now I would like to create an instance of `A`. It could look like this, however this syntax is not correct.

```
a = A
a.Print()
```

EDIT:

An even more complex example:

Suppose I have an object `C`, which purpose it is to store one single parameter and do some computations with it. The parameter, however, is not passed as such but it is embedded in a huge parameter file. It could look something like this:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, ParameterFile):
        self._Parameter = self._ExtractParamterFile(ParameterFile)
    def _ExtractParamterFile(self, ParameterFile):
        #does some complex magic to extract the right parameter
        return the_extracted_parameter
```

Now I would like to dump and load an instance of that object `C`. However, when I load this object, I only have the single variable `self._Parameter` and I cannot call the constructor, because it is expecting the parameter file.

```
    @staticmethod
    def Load(file):
        f = open(file, "rb")
        oldObject = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()

        #somehow create newObject without calling __init__
        newObject._Parameter = oldObject._Parameter
        return newObject
```

In other words, it is not possible to create an instance without passing the parameter file. In my "real" case, however, it is not a parameter file but some huge junk of data I certainly not want to carry around in memory or even store it to disc.

And since I want to return an instance of `C` from the method `Load` I do somehow have to call the constructor.

OLD EDIT:

A more complex example, which explains **why** I am asking the question:

```
class B(object):    
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self._Name = name
        #do something with data, but do NOT save data in a variable

    @staticmethod
    def Load(self, file, newName):
        f = open(file, "rb")
        s = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()

        newS = B(???)
        newS._Name = newName
        return newS
```

As you can see, since `data` is not stored in a class variable I cannot pass it to `__init__`. Of course I could simply store it, but what if the data is a huge object, which I do not want to carry around in memory all the time or even save it to disc?

Comment: To what end do you want to do this?

Comment: I have an "unpickled" object from which I want to create a new object of the same type. However, from this unpickled object I do not have enough data to feed to __init__. In C++ I would overload the constructor and make it private, in Python I am lost ^^. The current parameters in __init__ however make perfect sense. That is my predicament.

Comment: I don't understand why you people vote it down. It is interesting question and given the amount of magic possible in python I believe it is possible with metaclasses or so.

Comment: If this is the case, you should rewrite `__init__`, make its paramters optional or make an additional parameter that allows just basic creation without any initialization

Comment: What do you mean by circumvent? Do you mean not use it or make it so it doesn't have to be used, or do you mean disable it's use so that it is not callable?

Comment: @pajton I completely concur! In fact, the question is well stated, boiled down to a minimum of information to understand. Unfortunately people get scared too easily once their minds are forced to go outside their limited comprehensions.

Comment: @Woltan: I still don't understand. Are you doing something like this: `a0 = pickle.load(...); a1 = A(a0)`?

Comment: @Dominic I would like to know, if there is a way to actually create an object without that `__init__` is being called. So more or less the former of your two suggestions ^^.

Comment: 1. If you can change the code of class, rewrite it so `__init__` will not require any data. 2. If you can see the code of class, pass some default values. 3. If you can't even see the code of the class, check it's docs, do some experiments, find out it's default values and pass them. Or inherit a new class which doesn't require any data.

Comment: @Woltan Please, update you question with a problem you want to solve.  Do you have a possibility to change class code?

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't simply use the instance returned by `pickle.load` in your new edit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a class instance without calling initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168964/how-to-create-a-class-instance-without-calling-initializer)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You *can* circumvent `__init__` by calling `__new__` directly. Then you can create a object of the given type and call an alternative method for `__init__`. This is something that `pickle` would do.

However, first I'd like to stress very much that it is something that you ***shouldn't*** do and whatever you're trying to achieve, there are better ways to do it, some of which have been mentioned in the other answers. In particular, it's a *bad* idea to skip calling `__init__`.

When objects are created, more or less this happens:

```
a = A.__new__(A, *args, **kwargs)
a.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You could skip the second step.

**Here's why you *shouldn't* do this:** The purpose of `__init__` is to initialize the object, fill in all the fields and ensure that the `__init__` methods of the parent classes are also called. With `pickle` it is an exception because it tries to store all the data associated with the object (including *any* fields/instance variables that are set for the object), and so anything that was set by `__init__` the previous time would be restored by pickle, there's no need to call it again.

If you skip `__init__` and use an alternative initializer, you'd have a sort of a code duplication - there would be two places where the instance variables are filled in, and it's easy to miss one of them in one of the initializers or accidentally make the two fill the fields act differently. This gives the possibility of subtle bugs that aren't that trivial to trace (you'd have to *know* which initializer was called), and the code will be more difficult to maintain. Not to mention that you'd be in an even bigger mess if you're using inheritance - the problems will go up the inheritance chain, because you'd have to use this alternative initializer everywhere up the chain.

Also by doing so you'd be more or less overriding Python's instance creation and making your own. Python already does that for you pretty well, no need to go reinventing it and it will confuse people using your code.

**Here's what to best do instead:** Use a single `__init__` method that is to be called for all possible instantiations of the class that initializes all instance variables properly. For different modes of initialization use either of the two approaches:

1. Support different signatures for `__init__` that handle your cases by using optional arguments.
2. Create several class methods that serve as alternative constructors. Make sure they all create instances of the class in the normal way (i.e. calling `__init__`), [as shown by Roman Bodnarchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6384228), while performing additional work or whatever. It's best if they pass all the data to the class (and `__init__` handles it), but if that's impossible or inconvenient, you can set some instance variables after the instance was created and `__init__` is done initializing.

If `__init__` has an optional step (e.g. like processing that `data` argument, although you'd have to be more specific), you can either make it an optional argument or make a normal method that does the processing... or both.

Comment: One can even use `a = object.__new__(A)`, if you don't want an overwriten `A.__new__` to be called.

Comment: Valid use for this is if you are building a factory pattern and want to delegate construction to another class but also want to have a default construction in the case that you dont use a factory for the class.

`class ThreadPoolFactory : def PersistentThreadPool() : ThreadPool.__new__ .... build and log it `

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful for combining the factory-pattern with a manageable default __init__ method. Since __init__() is one of the first places user's engage with, it's helpful to keep its arguments (and docstring) user-readable. Providing all possible optional arguments for all possible constructors (subsets of which may be mutually exclusive) would lead to an unusable documentation nightmare. I suppose you could replace __init__() with an empty stub and a note saying "see the constructor methods", but at this point... it's about the same thing ( :

Answer (score 25):

Use `classmethod` decorator for your `Load` method:

```
class B(object):    
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self._Name = name
        #store data

    @classmethod
    def Load(cls, file, newName):
        f = open(file, "rb")
        s = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()

        return cls(newName, s)
```

So you can do:

```
loaded_obj = B.Load('filename.txt', 'foo')
```

Edit:

Anyway, if you still want to omit `__init__` method, try `__new__`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             print '__init__'
...
>>> A()
__init__
<__main__.A object at 0x800f1f710>
>>> a = A.__new__(A)
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x800f1fd50>
```

Comment: In this case in the line `return cls(newName, s)`, `data` would be `s`. But this is not the case, since I do not know what `data` is.

Comment: @Woltan I don't know as well.  Maybe you should expand your question once more?

Comment: The `return cls(newName, s)` is calling `__init__()`.

Comment: @martineau That is right, but the second parameter of `__init__` (`data`) is of different type thatn `s` (See my new Edit example)

Answer (score 11):

Taking your question literally I would use meta classes :

```
class MetaSkipInit(type):
    def __call__(cls):
        return cls.__new__(cls)


class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaSkipInit

    def __init__(self):
        print "FAILURE"

    def Print(self):
        print "YEHAA"


b = B()
b.Print()
```

This can be useful e.g. for copying constructors without polluting the parameter list.
But to do this properly would be more work and care than my proposed hack.

Comment: This is a nice solution showing exactly how to override the default `__new__` + `__init__` by implementing a custom `__call__` method on the metaclass level. It does so without any 'hacking' and allows you to do other useful stuff (like implementing a flyweight pattern) and keep that perfectly hidden from the user. For the user it still looks like a normal constructor call.

Answer (score 10):

Not really.  The purpose of `__init__` is to instantiate an object, and by default it really doesn't do anything.  If the `__init__` method is not doing what you want, and it's not your own code to change, you can choose to switch it out though.  For example, taking your class A, we could do the following to avoid calling that `__init__` method:

```
def emptyinit(self):
    pass
A.__init__ = emptyinit
a = A()
a.Print()
```

This will dynamically switch out which `__init__` method from the class, replacing it with an empty call.  Note that this is probably NOT a good thing to do, as it does not call the super class's `__init__` method.

You could also subclass it to create your own class that does everything the same, except overriding the `__init__` method to do what you want it to (perhaps nothing).

Perhaps, however, you simply wish to call the method from the class without instantiating an object.  If that is the case, you should look into the [@classmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [@staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorators.  They allow for just that type of behavior.

In your code you have put the @staticmethod decorator, which does not take a `self` argument.  Perhaps what may be better for the purpose would a @classmethod, which might look more like this:

```
@classmethod
def Load(cls, file, newName):
    # Get the data
    data = getdata()
    # Create an instance of B with the data
    return cls.B(newName, data)
```

UPDATE: Rosh's Excellent answer pointed out that you CAN avoid calling `__init__` by implementing `__new__`, which I was actually unaware of (although it makes perfect sense).  Thanks Rosh!

Answer (score 9):

I was reading the Python cookbook and there's a section talking about this: the example is given using `__new__` to bypass `__init__()`

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a


>>> test = A('a')
>>> test.a
'a'
>>> test_noinit = A.__new__(A)
>>> test_noinit.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    test_noinit.a
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'a'
>>>
```

However I think this only works in Python3. Below is running under 2.7

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a


>>> test = A.__new__(A)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    test = A.__new__(A)
AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__new__'
>>>
```

Comment: With 2.7 you need to use a “new style class” — that is, subclass object: `class A(object)`.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment you could change your `__init__` method so that it allows creation without giving any values to its parameters:

```
def __init__(self, p0, p1, p2):
   # some logic
```

would become:

```
def __init__(self, p0=None, p1=None, p2=None):
   if p0 and p1 and p2:
       # some logic
```

or:

```
def __init__(self, p0=None, p1=None, p2=None, init=True):
    if init:
        # some logic
```

Comment: Yeah, I could make parameters default, but this actually does not answer my question. But maybe you are right, and I have a some sort of layout problem in my class.