# How to create an instance of subclass from a factory (i.e., constructor) which invokes the super __init__ directly?

Tags: python

I have an abstract class A, and a concrete subclass B. B has a constructor with a large code base depending on it but now I need a new way to construct instances of B without impacting the dependent code, so I need to create an instance of B from a new constructor factory method and by invoking B's parent constructor directly.

Code before the refactoring:

```
from abc import ABC 

class A(ABC):
  def __init__(self, k, l, m, n)
     # complex initialization ...
     self._x = x
     self._y = y

class B(A):
   def __init__(self, k, l, m, n):
      super().__init__(k, l, m, n)
      # additional code here for initializing B's side
```

Code after the refactoring:

```
from abc import ABC 

class A(ABC):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
     self._x = x
     self._y = y

  @classmethod
  def _complex_initialization(cls, k, l, m, n): 
     # <<< complex initialization code here that uses cls >>>>
     return x, y

class B(A):
   def __init__(self, k, l, m, n):
      x, y = self._complex_initialization(k, l, m, n)
      super().__init__(x, y)

   @classmethod
   def _create_from_x_y(cls, x, y):
      # is this correct? I need an instance of B but 
      # initialized using the constructor of A
      return super(B, A).__init__(x, y)
```

I need in `B._create_from_x_y(x, y)` to be able to create an instance of B initialized using A's constructor.

Comment: First of all, python is not java. You shouldn't bring Java concepts into a python program

Comment: who talked about java, if you don't understand what I am asking then skip, your comment is a waste of time

Comment: You're missing a bunch of `self` and `cls` parameters. Please [edit] to fix your code.

Comment: @wjandrea, thanks a lot! fixed

Comment: The example still seems quite incoherent, which makes it hard to say what the right answer might look like. You have an ABC with no abstract methods, a child that knows all about its parent's complex initialisation method (but apparently not what it returns) and an alternate constructor that's _private_. (Also: 3-space indentation?)

Comment: you can have helper methods in the super class to support multiple sub classes, is called reuse. This is a simple MRE of the problem, of course I am not going to write a lot of subclasses that would also reuse the complex initialization.

Comment: @SkyWalker still not fully fixed, and I think a key issue is `_complex_initialization`. It is defined as a classmethod, but first argument is `k`. in `B.__init__` this function is called and is expected to return two variables, but at the moment it simply returns `None`. Please add a fully working example, with what you expect to have as the instance's values of `k, l, m, n, _x, _y`

Comment: The short answer is already in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6383914/3001761, but most likely there's a totally different way to go about this.

Comment: Did it actually have to be an instance of B? It would be much simpler to have separate A-children B *and C* each giving different initialisation guarantees. FWIW, why does A define `_complex_initialization` but B calls it? This looks like there is a strong coupling that isn’t actually fixed by just avoiding init.

Comment: If the thing is about OOP, it's not only how to fix some method, but it's about the Design. I don't think the design is worked out well here.

Comment: For all the haters, there is ofc a clean rewrite which would impact a large code base, I can not change B's existing constructor interface, that is the whole point.

Comment: @SkyWalker As in, absolutely not at all change init? Not even, say, introduce a `skip_complex_init` parameter? Or kwargs to check whether klmn or xy were given?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi indeed that's an idea but I would not go down that path, makes the code harder to understand and more complex too. With the additional constructor it is clear what is intended, communication of intent.

Comment: @SkyWalker Almost fixed. Now `_create_from_x_y` takes `cls` but never uses it.

Comment: @wjandrea please don't be so pedantic, this is a very simple demonstration of the real problem.

Comment: @SkyWalker Oh wait, it's not pedantic; that's what you're trying to ask, how to create an instance of `cls`! Sorry, I got so wrapped up in the other problems (like `super(B, A)`) that I couldn't understand what you're asking. This might be a duplicate of [How to create a class instance without calling initializer?](/q/2168964/4518341), though the top answer is really Python-2-heavy.

Comment: @wjandrea thanks a lot! yes took a look but I like better the answer from Nathan, you don't need to break a sweat to implement it and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how you can modify the _create_from_x_y method:

```
from abc import ABC 

class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @classmethod
    def _complex_initialization(cls, k, l, m, n):
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, k, l, m, n):
        x, y = self._complex_initialization(k, l, m, n)
        super().__init__(x, y)

    @classmethod
    def _create_from_x_y(cls, x, y):
        # Create new instance of B without calling its constructor
        obj = cls.__new__(cls)
        
        # Calling the constructor of A with the instance of B
        A.__init__(obj, x, y)
        
        return obj
```

Comment: FWIW, `A.__init__` could be replaced by use of `super` here. This would at least not further weld the two classes together, which seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi could you add an additional answer? this would be interesting for me and many others surely to see.

Comment: NP @SkyWalker  ^^ Computing Science is not exact like maths. :)
Curious to have the answer of MisterMiyagi too !

Comment: @Nathan I know I know, I've been in this business for more than 25 years ;) I needed your solution to prevent a massive code base impact.

Comment: @SkyWalker Impressive ! Good luck so ! I do code since around 1 year lol I'm a chick.

Comment: @Bibhav If I'm not mistaken, that wouldn't work with inheritance since `super()` could lookup on B. I think what you actually want is `super(B, obj).__init__(x, y)`.

Comment: @wjandrea which gets closer to what I thought of in the OP :D