# Convert objects hierarchy from MATLAB to to python

Tags: python, matlab, coding-style

I am converting a MATLAB script into python. The MATLAB script uses some kind of objects hierarchy for different input variables as in:

```
parameterA.subparameter1= A1;
parameterA.subparameter2= A2;

parameterB.subparameter1= B1;
parameterB.subparameter2= B2;
```

Where `A1,A2,B1,B2` can all be strings and numbers. I wish to convert this to python and I have used

```
parameterA.subparameter1= A1
parameterA.subparameter2= A2

parameterB.subparameter1= B1
parameterB.subparameter2= B2
```

Now I am getting the error:

> NameError: name 'parameterA' is not defined

I have tried to initialize them by using either `parameterA,parameterB=[],[]`, which is not good because I want objects and not a list or `parameterA,parameterB=set(),set()` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476816/creating-an-empty-object-in-python) as well as some other solution.

Is this at all the correct approach? How do I initialize this structure? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you use `dict`s instead. These are efficient and versatile built-in objects in python.

```
parameterA  = {'subparameter1': A1} # definition
parameterA['subparameter2'] = A2 # update/assignment

parameterB = {'subparameter1': B1, 'subparameter2': B2}
```

As you can see you can access and modify values using square brackets. If you *really* insist on using attribute lookup, you could use `types.SimpleNamespace`:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

parameterA = SimpleNamespace(subparameter1=A1)
parameterA.subparameter2 = A2

parameterB = SimpleNamespace(subparameter1=B1, subparameter2=B2)
```

The main reason I'd stick to dicts is the ease with which you can access keys dynamically. Only use a `SimpleNamespace` or something similar if you never access attributes programmatically, because your objects are more like a tool for grouping variables together. You can still access attributes programmatically, but it's uglier (and less idiomatic) than `dict` item lookup.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handle-data-returned-from-matlab-to-python.html) for the Python Engine for MATLAB you can find a disambiguation of classes in MATLAB to classes in Python.

If you want to fit the documentation, you should replace structs in MATLAB with dictionaries in Python (like [Andras Deak answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54179146/7545157)). If you want to keep the syntax for calling the structure fields with dot-operator you can also define classes in Python.

```
class parameterA: pass
class parameterB: pass

parameterA.subparameter1= A1
parameterA.subparameter2= A2

parameterB.subparameter1= B1
parameterB.subparameter2= B2
```

---

... But I also would recommend dictionaries.