# Getting the match number when passing a function in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-re

When using a function in `re.sub`:

```
import re
def custom_replace(match):
    # how to get the match number here? i.e. 0, 1, 2
    return 'a'
print(re.sub(r'o', custom_replace, "oh hello wow"))
```

**How to get the match number inside `custom_replace`?**

i.e. 0, 1, 2 for the three "o" of the example input string.

NB: I don't want to use a global variable for this, because multiple such operations might happen in different threads etc.

Comment: What do you mean with the match number?

Comment: @Jan I mean 0, 1, 2 for the three "o" of the example input string.

Comment: Should `re.sub` be only used?

Comment: @Ch3steR I'm open to other solutions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Barmar's answer, I tried this:

```
import re

def custom_replace(match, matchcount):
    result = 'a' + str(matchcount.i)
    matchcount.i += 1
    return result

def any_request():
    matchcount = lambda: None  # an empty "object", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476816/creating-an-empty-object-in-python/37540574#37540574
    matchcount.i = 0           # benefit : it's a local variable that we pass to custom_replace "as reference
    print(re.sub(r'o', lambda match: custom_replace(match, matchcount), "oh hello wow"))
    # a0h hella1 wa2w

any_request()
```

and it seems to work.

Reason: I was a bit reluctant to use a global variable for this, because I'm using this inside a web framework, in a route function (called `any_request()` here).
Let's say there are many requests in parallel (in threads), I don't want a global variable to be "mixed" between different calls (since the operations are probably not atomic?)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way. You can use a global variable as a counter.

```
def custom_replace(match):
    global match_num
    result = 'a' + str(match_num)
    match_num += 1
    return result

match_num = 0
print(re.sub(r'o', custom_replace, "oh hello wow"))
```

Output is

```
a0h hella1 wa2w
```

Don't forget to reset `match_num` to `0` before each time you call `re.sub()` with this function.

Comment: Or set it to `0` before the call, as I showed above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Barmar. I was a bit reluctant to use a global variable for this, because I'm using this inside a web framework, in a route request. Let's say there are many requests in parallel (in threads?), I don't want this global variable to be "mixed" between different calls (which are not atomic?).

Comment: What do you think about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086537/getting-the-match-number-when-passing-a-function-in-re-sub/61087415#61087415? It's a shame there's no built-in attribute inside `match` to give the match number :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search` with `re.sub`.

```
def count_sub(pattern,text,repl=''):
    count=1
    while re.search(pattern,text):
        text=re.sub(pattern,repl+str(count),text,count=1)
        count+=1
    return text
```

Output:

```
count_sub(r'o', 'oh hello world')
# '1h hell2 w3rld'

count_sub(r'o', 'oh hello world','a')
# 'a1h hella2 wa3rld'
```

Alternative:

```
def count_sub1(pattern,text,repl=''):
    it=enumerate(re.finditer(pattern,text),1)
    count=1
    while count:
        count,_=next(it,(0,0))
        text=re.sub(pattern,repl+str(count),text,count=1)
    return text
```

Output:

```
count_sub1(r'o','oh hello world')
# '1h hell2 w3rld'

count_sub1(r'o','oh hello world','a')
# 'a1h hella2 wa3rld'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't it a problem to modify `text` while looping on `re.search(pattern, text)`? Isn't this dangerous?

Comment: @Basj I have no idea TBH. But added another alternative. Not expert in regex. How can it be dangerous? If there's any link or resource point me to it.