# How to generalize passing callbacks into tkinter notebook?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to generalize the addition of buttons and tabs in a `tkinter.ttk.Notebook`. Here's what I have so far:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Frame
from tkinter import Button, Tk

f1 = lambda: print("f1")
f2 = lambda: print("f2")
f3 = lambda: print("f3")
f4 = lambda: print("f4")
f5 = lambda: print("f5")
f6 = lambda: print("f6")
f7 = lambda: print("f7")

frames = ["F1", "F2", "F3"]
labels = [('f1', 'f2', 'f3'), ('f4', 'f5'), ('f6', 'f7')]
commands = [(f1, f2, f3), (f4, f5), (f6, f7)]

tk = Tk()
notebook = Notebook(tk)

for i, f in enumerate(frames):
  frame = Frame(notebook)
  notebook.add(frame, text=f)
  for j, label in enumerate(labels[i]):
    button = Button(frame, text=label, command=commands[i][j])
    button.pack()
notebook.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Now, suppose I want function `f7` not to print the string `'f7'`, but rather to perform a `frame.quit` so I can exit out of the notebook.

How can I call `frame.quit` and keep the generic nature of the code above?
I don't know how I could do that before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I thought of doing this. The first is to create an empty object ([using the method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476841/7519434)) before the lambdas and then by the time the function is called `frame` is properly defined.

```
frame = type('', (), {})()
f1 = lambda: print("f1")
f2 = lambda: print("f2")
f3 = lambda: print("f3")
f4 = lambda: print("f4")
f5 = lambda: print("f5")
f6 = lambda: print("f6")
f7 = lambda: print(frame.quit)
```

If several of your functions are going to make reference to the frame you could pass a reference to it instead, but then every lambda will need to take it as a parameter.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Frame
from tkinter import Button, Tk

f1 = lambda f: print("f1")
f2 = lambda f: print("f2")
f3 = lambda f: print("f3")
f4 = lambda f: print("f4")
f5 = lambda f: print("f5")
f6 = lambda f: print("f6")
f7 = lambda f: f.quit()



frames = ["F1", "F2", "F3"]
labels = [('f1', 'f2', 'f3'), ('f4', 'f5'), ('f6', 'f7')]
commands = [(f1, f2, f3), (f4, f5), (f6, f7)]

tk = Tk()
notebook = Notebook(tk)

for i, f in enumerate(frames):
  frame = Frame(notebook)
  notebook.add(frame, text=f)
  for j, label in enumerate(labels[i]):
    button = Button(frame, text=label, command= lambda: commands[i][j](frame))
    button.pack()
notebook.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make several changes to support what you want.

1. Add a generic `*args` argument to each of the seven default `F*` functions that are defined so they will work if any arguments get passed to them (like `frame`).
2. Change the `commands` variable from a list-of-tuples to a list-of-lists to make its subsequences mutable.
3. Make the `Button`s `command=` keyword argument value a `lambda` and with several arguments, some of the with default values. This make it look-up values at runtime.

```
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Frame
from tkinter import Button, Tk

f1 = lambda *args: print("f1")
f2 = lambda *args: print("f2")
f3 = lambda *args: print("f3")
f4 = lambda *args: print("f4")
f5 = lambda *args: print("f5")
f6 = lambda *args: print("f6")
f7 = lambda *args: print("f7")

frames = ["F1", "F2", "F3"]
labels = [('f1', 'f2', 'f3'), ('f4', 'f5'), ('f6', 'f7')]
commands = [[f1, f2, f3], [f4, f5], [f6, f7]]  # CHANGED TO LIST OF SUBLISTS

tk = Tk()
notebook = Notebook(tk)

for i, f in enumerate(frames):
    frame = Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(frame, text=f)
    for j, label in enumerate(labels[i]):
        button = Button(frame, text=label, command=lambda i=i, j=j: commands[i][j](frame))
        button.pack()
notebook.pack()

commands[2][1] = lambda frame: frame.quit()  # Change the F7 slot.

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something slightly different, which worked:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Frame
from tkinter import Button, Tk

tk = Tk()
notebook = Notebook(tk)

f1 = lambda: print("f1")
f2 = lambda: print("f2")
f3 = lambda: print("f3")
f4 = lambda: print("f4")
f5 = lambda: print("f5")
f6 = lambda: print("f6")
f7 = lambda: notebook.quit()

frames = ["F1", "F2", "F3"]
labels = [('f1', 'f2', 'f3'), ('f4', 'f5'), ('f6', 'f7')]
commands = [(f1, f2, f3), (f4, f5), (f6, f7)]

for i, f in enumerate(frames):
  frame = Frame(notebook)
  notebook.add(frame, text=f)
  for j, label in enumerate(labels[i]):
    button = Button(frame, text=label, command=commands[i][j])
    button.pack()
notebook.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```